# How does GNU Parallel handle multithreaded jobs?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Does GNU Parallel change job assignment based upon how many threads each job uses?

For example, on an 8 core machine, does

```
parallel 4ThreadedProcess
```

automatically detect that each job uses 4 threads and thus run only 2 jobs at a time?

Comment: No, it has no idea how many threads your job will start.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's what I thought. I guess I'll just have to manually specify `-j`.

Comment: @Geremia Remember that you can use %. So for a 4 threaded process on a machine with 8 CPU threads use: -j25%. This way if you upgrade to a machine with 24 CPU threads then it will still use the full machine.